# Why does dynamically adding a QTreeWidget to a QStackedWidget reset the font style?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a script (modeled by `dialog.py`) which contains a stacked widget that embeds a custom widget module (modeled by `widget_1.py`) into the first page. The user clicks the 'Switch Page' button to add another page to the stacked widget and embed it with a different widget (using `widget_1.py` here again since it is easy to see the problem later). Everything works out except the style guide for some of the items are ignored in the added page while others are not. Why?

[image: First page of stacked widget with correct font styling]

First page of stacked widget with correct font styling.

[image: Second page of stacked widget with default font styling]

Second page of stacked widget with default font styling.

`dialog.py`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from widget_1 import widget_1_UI

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.resize(640, 480)
        Dialog.setWindowTitle("I'm a cat. I'm a kitty cat.")
        self.addPage2 = False
        
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        
        
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(Dialog)
        
        
        self.page_1 = widget_1_UI()
        self.page_1.setupUi(self.page_1)
        self.stackedWidget.insertWidget(0, self.page_1)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)                        
        
        
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        
        
        self.btn_nextPage = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.btn_nextPage.setText("Switch Page")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_nextPage)
        self.btn_nextPage.clicked.connect(self.addSecond)
        self.btn_nextPage.clicked.connect(self.nextPage)

        
    def nextPage(self):
        num = self.stackedWidget.currentIndex()       
        if num == 0:
            self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        else:
            self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
            
    def addSecond(self):
        if not self.addPage2:
            self.page_2 = widget_1_UI()
            self.page_2.setupUi(self.page_2)
            self.stackedWidget.insertWidget(1, self.page_2)
            self.addPage2 = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`widget_1.py`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class widget_1_UI(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.resize(614, 411)
        Form.setWindowTitle("Main Dialog")
        
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Narrow")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setText("Cat Type")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        
        self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Narrow")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        
        self.treeWidget.setFont(font)        
        self.treeWidget.header().setVisible(False)
        self.catTypes = ["Happy", "Sleepy", "Hangry", "Needy", "Kneedy"]
        self.catSubtype = ["Orange", "Black", "Brown", "White"]
        for index in range(len(self.catTypes)):
            item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
            item_0.setText(0, self.catTypes[index])
            for count in range(len(self.catSubtype)):
                item_1 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(item_0)
                item_1.setText(0, self.catSubtype[count])                        
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.treeWidget)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce at least on Linux. Does it happen with other fonts too? And does it happen also if you directly call `addSecond()` and `nextPage()` in the `setupUi()`?

Comment: @musicamante I'm running on Windows 10 and yes any font produces the same result. If I'm interpreting what you mean correctly, then it does not occur if I add the second page in the same manner as the first. It only occurs when it is added adhoc like this. Is it possible to set the font of the stacked widget and bypass having to define it in widget_1.py? Edit: Tried this and still no luck.